# Flutter digital clock widget causing errors as soon as the view is changed

Tags: flutter, mobile, widget

Im using https://pub.dev/packages/slide_digital_clock and its causing memory leak and animation error spam and i do not how to fix it , this happens as soon as the the view is sent back to logout. if any one can explain show how it can be fixed it would be much appreciated

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:attenv02/login_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:slide_digital_clock/slide_digital_clock.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 var locationMessege= "";
 bool timeinbtn = true;
 bool timeoutbtn = false;
 String name = "";

 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 }

Future <String> loadPref()async{
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),()async{
  return await sharedPreferences.getString("useFullName");
});

}


 logout()async{
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
sharedPreferences.clear();
sharedPreferences.commit();
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) 
=> LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
}


void getCurrentLocation()async{
var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
var lastPosition=await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();
String now =await new DateFormat.yMd().add_Hm().format(new DateTime.now());
timeinbtn=!timeinbtn;
timeoutbtn=!timeoutbtn;
print(lastPosition);
print(now);

setState(() {
  locationMessege="$position.latitude,$position.longitude,$now";
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor:Color.fromRGBO(255, 191, 68, 1),
    title:FutureBuilder(
      future: loadPref(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return Text("${snapshot.data}");
        }else{
          return Text("Loading");
        }
      },
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          logout();
        },
        child: Text("Log Out", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/bg.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [

            Column(
              children:<Widget>  [
                Container(
                    child:DigitalClock(
                      digitAnimationStyle: Curves.elasticOut,
                      is24HourTimeFormat: false,
                      areaDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                      hourMinuteDigitTextStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        fontSize: 50,
                      ),
                      amPmDigitTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                ),

                Text("Position:$locationMessege",style:TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 10.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Visibility(
                  visible:timeinbtn,
                  child: FlatButton(onPressed:(){
                    getCurrentLocation();
                  },
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      child: Text("Time in",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),)),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: timeoutbtn,
                  child: FlatButton(onPressed:(){
                    getCurrentLocation();
                  },
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      child: Text("Time out",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),)),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
_SpinnerTextState#321b2(ticker active) was disposed with an active Ticker.

_SpinnerTextState created a Ticker via its SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, but at the time dispose() was called on the mixin, that Ticker was still active. The Ticker must be disposed before calling super.dispose().

Tickers used by AnimationControllers should be disposed by calling dispose() on the AnimationController itself. Otherwise, the ticker will leak.

Exception caught by animation library
The following assertion was thrown while notifying listeners for AnimationController:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4109 pos 12: '_lifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.

Exception caught by animation library
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4109 pos 12: '_lifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.

Exception caught by animation library
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4109 pos 12: '_lifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package has two bugs and there are two pull requests to fix these issues, but you have to merge them manually because these two pull requests did not merge by owner
Step 1: update `lib/helpers/spinner_text.dart` https://github.com/caglarylmz/slide_digital_clock/pull/4/files/23cd40ac4f32fc7adeab4101af498994d40d43fd
change from

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _spinTextAnimationController.dispose();
  }
```

to

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _spinTextAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();        
  }
```

Step 2: Cancel timer, update class `_DigitalClockState` https://github.com/caglarylmz/slide_digital_clock/pull/1/commits/5a648954e83e8215180e05db5bbf9e232e4d385a
code snippet

```
Timer _timer;
...
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
...
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

working demo after manually merged these two pull requests

[image]

full code of working demo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:slide_digital_clock/slide_digital_clock.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var locationMessege = "";
  bool timeinbtn = true;
  bool timeoutbtn = false;
  String name = "";

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<String> loadPref() async {
    /*SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
      return await sharedPreferences.getString("useFullName");
    });*/

    return Future.value("useFullName");
  }

  logout() async {
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    /*var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    var lastPosition = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();
    String now = await new DateFormat.yMd().add_Hm().format(new DateTime.now());
    timeinbtn = !timeinbtn;
    timeoutbtn = !timeoutbtn;
    print(lastPosition);
    print(now);

    setState(() {
      locationMessege = "$position.latitude,$position.longitude,$now";
    });*/
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 191, 68, 1),
        title: FutureBuilder(
          future: loadPref(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text("${snapshot.data}");
            } else {
              return Text("Loading");
            }
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              logout();
            },
            child: Text("Log Out", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        /*decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),*/
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: DigitalClock(
                        digitAnimationStyle: Curves.elasticOut,
                        is24HourTimeFormat: false,
                        areaDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                        ),
                        hourMinuteDigitTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          fontSize: 50,
                        ),
                        amPmDigitTextStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text("Position:$locationMessege",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 10.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: timeinbtn,
                      child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            getCurrentLocation();
                          },
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          child: Text(
                            "Time in",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: timeoutbtn,
                      child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            getCurrentLocation();
                          },
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          child: Text(
                            "Time out",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          )),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Login Page")));
  }
}
```

Comment: do apologize if its a stupid question but do i need to create a file or find the package file, i do not have lib/helpers/spinner_text.dart file in my lib folder the main lib that contain my app darts

Comment: You can copy paste all code in github to your project and then modify it. or fork this github project direcctly.

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: where exactly do i copy it, do i need to create a new dart as lib/helpers/spinner_text.dart ?, where can i find this spinner_text.dart ?

Comment: Yes. you can copy all files and follow owner's directory https://github.com/caglarylmz/slide_digital_clock/tree/master/lib to your project

Comment: please check these images https://ibb.co/jhftr0S thats the error im keep getting and this is my file structure for lib https://ibb.co/8MXQ8WK please confirm if i did it correctly, i made all the changes asked in the git

Comment: Can not reproduce. please post reproduce code or post your project to github. so more people can help you. thanks.

Comment: according to error message. please check step 1 and make _spinTextAnimationController.dispose(); before super.dispose();

Comment: Ok i clean the project remove the clock from dependencies and included the slide_digital_clock.dart file from my lib directly , i dont know how you managed to include the  dependencies package include and got it to work, anyways it works now thank you for your help